# angular 4 component call multiple time same service

Tags: angular

I have an application in angular 4 and i had builded almost all the components in this way:

```
 export class AreaProdottiComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {

    subscription: ISubscription;


    constructor(private someservice:Service){
        this.subscription = someserviceObservable.subscribe(
                res=>{
                    console.log('everything ok')
                }
        )
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.someservice.fn()
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

these components interact with services built almost in this way:

```
export class Service(){        
    someservicesubj=Subject<any>();
    someserviceObservable=someservicesubj.asObservable();

    fn(){
        doCall.subscribe(
                res=>{
                    this.someservicesubj.next();
                }
        )
    }

    doCall()Observable<any>{
        //some http call is here
    }
}
```

So when components like this are created they call for an automatic HTTP method from the services, and everything seems to work, but if I navigate the application and I return to the same component for the second time the number of calls that make as soon as the component is created are doubled, the fn method is called 2 times. This behavior increases every time I destroy and recreate the component.

Example:

Opening the component in the console i'll read 'everything ok', go out and return i'll read 'everything ok' 3 times, the old one plus 2 other.

I think i miss something in the navigation strategy or in the building of the service, but i really don't ifnd the solution.

## Update

I had tried as @trichetriche  has suggested but it still donesn't work. i had used ISubscription instead is that the possible problem?

## Update

@trichetriche Was right but i had a service called inside another subscriber and so i missed the fact that was the first service that was unsubscribed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because subscriptions need to be closed when you open them. And you don't close them.

I won't comment on the uneccessity of creating subjects for HTTP calls though.

```js
export class AreaProdottiComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private someservice:Service){
    this.subscription = someserviceObservable.subscribe(res => console.log('everything ok'));
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.someservice.fn()
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

If you want to automatically unsubscribe from the subscriptions, you can use a decorator for that.

```js
export const randomString = () => Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);

export function AutoUnsubscribe(blacklist = []) {
  return function (constructor) {
    const original = constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy;
    constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function () {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:forin
      for (const prop in this) {
        const property = this[prop];
        if (!blacklist.includes(prop)) {
          if (property && (typeof property.unsubscribe === 'function')) {
            property.unsubscribe();
            // console.log(prop + ' unsubscribed');
          }
        }
      }
      if (original && typeof original === 'function') { original.apply(this, arguments); }
    };
  };
}
```

Now your component would look like this

```js
@AutoUnsubscribe()
export class AreaProdottiComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private someservice:Service){
    this[randomString()] = someserviceObservable.subscribe(res => console.log('everything ok'));
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.someservice.fn()
  }
}
```

Comment: "I won't comment on the uneccessity of creating subjects for HTTP calls though." Nice one :-D

Comment: Well, I cried a little when I saw, the least I could do was to make him notice it was uneccessary !

Comment: Ok maybe it was a problem and i've done what you told but nothing change, still callng x time

Comment: Then you did it wrong. Unsubscribing from a subscription will prevent multiple calls. Do you have subscriptions declared into subscriptions ?

Comment: Update with your real code, not pseudo-examples of what you're doing. For all I know, your log can come from the service, not the component. And use `Subscription`, not `ISubscription`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that you never unsubscribe the subscriptions you create in the components constructor. Every time the component gets instantiated, a new subscription is opened and therefore the logs increase by one, every time you navigate to that component.

If you want to prevent this behavior, you should save the subscription and close it in the `ngOnDestroy` method:

```
export class AreaProdottiComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private someservice:Service){
        this.subscription = someserviceObservable.subscribe(
                res=>{
                    console.log('everything ok')
                }
        )
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.someservice.fn()
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the subscription to the variable

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks for the hint, fixed it.